# Issue setting alignment of labels

Tags: html, css, alignment

I have a problem setting the alignment of my links.

[image]

I need `Yesterday` `This week` `This month` to be perfectly aligned with **DateTime From** and `Last 2 days` `Last 7 days` `Last 30 days` with **DateTime To** labels.

How it looks in the html:

```
<div class="row clear">
                                    <label>
                                        DateTime From
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="items">
                                        <input type="text" wicket:id="dtFrom" id="dtFrom" class="wdate pickdate"
                                               placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
                                        <input type="text" wicket:id="timeFrom" placeholder="hh:mm"/>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="yesterday">Yesterday</a>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="thisWeek">This week</a>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="thisMonth">This month</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row clear">
                                    <label>
                                        DateTime To
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="items">
                                        <input type="text" wicket:id="dtTo" class="wdate pickdate"
                                               placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
                                        <input type="text" wicket:id="timeTo" placeholder="hh:mm"/>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="last2Days">Last 2 days</a>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="last7Days">Last 7 days</a>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="last30Days">Last 30 days</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```

I have pretty basic knowledge of html, so I can't figure it out how to align them properly. Would be thankful for any help.

Comment: can you share full code or more details because i try in my editor it's working fine for me

Comment: @HarshShah hmm, I don't know what else to share with you. There's a lot more code there that is not related to these labels. What could be the problem then? What details could I provide you?

Comment: @Martin Are you using bootstrap? or any other css class?

Comment: @NijinKoderi hmm, no? does that count? `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/corp_logs.css" media="all">`

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this tag `<div class="row clear">` in your code at first line

Comment: Where exactly? It doesn't help

Answer (score 0):

I try this code it is properly working

You want exactly same right?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/KFrhl.png

Comment: Yes, but it's not working for me, maybe somethign is interfering with it?

Answer (score 0):

It is working fine here..check it out. May be in your css file they gave some style element like margin...!!

try giving inline giving margin values

```html
<div class="row clear">
                                    <label>
                                        DateTime From
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="items">
                                        <input type="text" wicket:id="dtFrom" id="dtFrom" class="wdate pickdate"
                                               placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
                                        <input type="text" wicket:id="timeFrom" placeholder="hh:mm"/>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="yesterday">Yesterday</a>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="thisWeek">This week</a>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="thisMonth">This month</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row clear">
                                    <label>
                                        DateTime To
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="items">
                                        <input type="text" wicket:id="dtTo" class="wdate pickdate"
                                               placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"/>
                                        <input type="text" wicket:id="timeTo" placeholder="hh:mm"/>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="last2Days">Last 2 days</a>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="last7Days">Last 7 days</a>
                                        <a href="#" wicket:id="last30Days">Last 30 days</a>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
```